# What's the right way to quote $(command $arg)?

Tags: bash, quoting, command-substitution

It's high time to solve this conundrum that's been bothering me for years...

I've been meeting this from time to time and thought this is the way to go:

```
$(comm "$(arg)")
```

And thought my view was strongly supported by experience. But I'm not so sure anymore. [Shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) can't make up its mind too. It's both:

```
"$(dirname $0)"/stop.bash
           ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

And:

```
$(dirname "$0")/stop.bash
^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
```

What's the logic behind?

(It's Shellcheck version 0.4.4, btw.)

Comment: Quote all substitutions.

Comment: Just like this: `"$(dirname "$0")"/stop.bash`? It seems to work... What's the story?

Comment: bash is smart enough to know when the context has changed.

Comment: think about it like this : `shell_level_1  $(shell_level_2) shell_level_1` : when you are inside the `$(....)` you enter a "sublevel" of shell, BUT you can write in it as if you were on primary level (ie, you can directly write `"` instead of `\"` , etc). ex:  `touch "/tmp/a file" ; echo "its size is: $(find "/tmp/a file" -ls | awk '{print $5}) ..."  : if you used backticks you'd have to `find \"/tmp/a file\"` and `print \$5`. With `$(...)` no need: the shell adapts to the new level and you can write directly as if your interpreter now is at that level too.

Comment: "Shellcheck can't make up its mind too." - The two runs have two different messages and point at different places.  It wants both.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to use `"$(somecmd "$file")"`.

Without the quotes, a path with a space will be split in the argument to `somecmd`, and it will target the wrong file. So you need quotes on the inside.

Any spaces in the output of `somecmd` will also cause splitting, so you need quotes on the outside of the whole command substitution.

*Quotes inside the command substitution have no effect on the quotes outside of it.* Bash's own reference manual isn't too clear on this, but [BashGuide explicitly mentions it](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution). The [text in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) also requires it, as *"any valid shell script"* is allowed inside `$(...)`:

> With the `$(command)` form, all characters following the open parenthesis to the matching closing parenthesis constitute the command. Any valid shell script can be used for command, except a script consisting solely of redirections which produces unspecified results.

---

Example:

```
$ file="./space here/foo"
```

a. No quotes, `dirname` processes both `./space` and `here/foo`:

```
$ printf "<%s>\n" $(dirname $file)
<.>
<here>
```

b. Quotes inside, `dirname` processes `./space here/foo`, giving `./space here`, which is split in two:

```
$ printf "<%s>\n" $(dirname "$file")
<./space>
<here>
```

c. Quotes outside, `dirname` processes both `./space` and `here/foo`, outputs on separate lines, but *now the two lines form a single argument*:

```
$ printf "<%s>\n" "$(dirname $file)"
<.
here>
```

d. Quotes both inside and outside, this gives the correct answer:

```
$ printf "<%s>\n" "$(dirname "$file")"
<./space here>
```

<sub>(that would possibly have been simpler if `dirname` only processed the first argument, but that wouldn't show the difference between cases a and c.)</sub>

Note that with `dirname` (and possibly others) you also need want to add `--`, to prevent the filename from being taken as an option in case it happens to start with a dash, so use `"$(dirname -- "$file")"`.

Comment: Note: In general, quotes don't nest in bash; but in this case, the `$( )` creates a new context, so the quotes inside it are independent of the quotes outside it. And you generally want quotes in both contexts.