# Assigning stdout value to a variable

Tags: shell-script, shell

So I'm trying to make a sh script where I put a value that I get from a command, into a variable, in this case n, but I have no idea what I'm doing, and this here obviously doesn't work lol:

```
  1 n=0
  2 cat test | grep -cE '[0-9]{1,4}' > $n
  3 echo "there were $n lines in test" > rtest1
```

It makes a rtest1 file which says "there were 0 lines in test"

Test is a file that has 10 lines, by the way.

So how does one assign a value from stdout to a variable in shell scripting? :D

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
file=./path/to/some/file
n="$(grep -cE '[0-9]{1,4}' < "$file")"
echo "there were $n matching lines in $file"
```

Of course you don't need the quotes in the assignment, just `n=$(...)` would do. But in general you want the quotes around the command substitution. Also note that it eats trailing newlines.

See also:

- [What's the right way to quote $(command $arg)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/443989/170373)
- [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/170373)

Comment: When I replace "$file" with "$test" (the name of my file which is in the same directory as the script) and run the script, I get:
Error on line1: no such file or directory

Comment: @iamAguest You need to assign the right name in the first line: `file=./test`