# extract 5 first lines of a text file to a variable

Tags: shell-script, variable, text, head, zenity

I'm wondering if it's possible to "extract" the first 5 lines of a textfile to a single variable (not an array)

for example:

`head -5 test.txt >$variable` (which of course doesn't work)

I'm trying to use zenity to display the first lines so I can confirm / cancel depending on the text displayed

```
zenity --question \
--text=$text
```

(other working solutions are of course appreciated...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as

```bsh
variable=`head -5 test.txt`
# or
variable=$(head -5 test.txt)
```

Looks like you are not well versed in shell scripting basics. Here's are nice guides:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters
- https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Comment: Please note that the "backtick" notation you showed in the first example is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) now; you may want to remove that. Also, it is generally advisable to [quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443989/whats-the-right-way-to-quote-command-arg) command substitutions (i.e. `variable="$(...)"`).

Comment: @AdminBee: There is no need to quote command substitutions when used for variable assignment.